# Wordpress error, "Are you sure you want to do this? Try again"

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ini, plesk

I hope you can help me, I am using a server running Parallels Plesk and installed WordPress as well. When I try to install a new theme, I am getting the following after 100% of uploading the theme:

> Are you sure you want to do this? Try again

I  have been seeking for a solution for hours now and facing all question raising the question on a forum.

So you see answers like the .ini file needs to be edited, but where .ini file  and by the answer you see that the .ini file getting edited with Unix commands.

As well you read that changing these setting might help.

```
max_execution_time 100
memory_limit 256M
post_max_size 32M
upload_max_filesize 32M
```

How do I change these setting with Plesk or is there somewhere a description where this been described step by step about how and where to change the setting in the PHP files?

Can you please navigate me to the solution to be able to upload themes?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to update the following setting in php.ini file. You can change it through plesk domain panel >> hosting setting and change it under the php setting.

```
max_execution_time = 180
max_input_time = 600
post_max_size = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 256M
```

Comment: Hi 24x7 servermanagement, Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I don't see any option where I should be able to change these setting at domain panel >> hosting setting. What will is next, this is exactly what I would like to change, but where and how.?

Comment: OK, found the solution, case can be closed.!